# How to copy the snapshot from CodeSnap VSCode Extension into clipboard without saving it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using the latest version of [CodeSnap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.codesnap) works properly on VSCode on Windows. It attempts to save the snapshot of a desired piece of code when I click on its symbol (1).

[image]

However, I'm not able to copy it to the clipboard directly as the docs suggest through (2). Instead, it copies the **code**.

> If you'd like to copy to clipboard instead of saving, click the image and press the copy keyboard shortcut (defaults are Ctrl+C on Windows and Linux, Cmd+C on OS X)

I also tried to follow the recommendation that follows without success:

> ... or bind codesnap.shutterAction to copy in your settings

But I wasn't able to configure it properly, because I couldn't find such setting. Is there any way to copy the snapshot without saving it before?

Comment: `codesnap.shutterAction` is a setting that has a string value and can only be: `save` or `copy`, in the Settings GUI go to the Codelens extension and change the setting

Comment: Life saver. I always find it difficult to remember this long path: `File > Preferences > Settings > search for extension > search for specific configuration`. I wonder if there wasn't a way to shorten it. Thank you again!

Comment: `Ctrl+,` and type part of the extension name or setting

Comment: The shutterAction is a nice hint, but sometimes it still would copy the code and not the image. Not always, but most of the times. And I can't really understand when and why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut to settings on VSCode on Windows is CTRL + < only.
I accidentally discovered this when I was intending on commenting HTML with Shift + < but then instead, by mistake pressed CTRL and the settings panel opened. This happened often

Answer (score 1):

you can go to setting and type **"Shutter Action"**  in search change it to **"copy"**,
when click on shutter action will copy this image insted of save it

Comment: This still copies the code when the code highlighted reaches a certain length